# C# Getting Serial Port In use error and can't understand why

Tags: c#, serial-port

Basically I need to communicate with a `COM serial printer`. There are 2 timers, one will print one ticket at time, and the others will hang up checking for errors and resuming the printing when the errors are gone.

For example: Printer is printing but if I press the pause button an error (read in the buffer) will get some booleans to 1 and after I read them I am able to tell what the error is and stop the printing.

My problem is in the method `ErrorTimer_Elapsed()` which is the timer elapsed event and probably is linked to the ErrorCheck and SendToCom (which is the printing method). The problem is that program detects errors well, but when in `ErrorTimer_Elapsed()` I try to repeatdly check for error status changes, I get IO errors like:

-Can't acces COM PORT
-The resource you required is in use

and so on.

Can you help me? Thanks, here's the code (about 180 lines), I'm bumping my head on this since 3 days :( :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        #region Variabili di istanza

        private ArrayList _filesToPrint = new ArrayList();  
        private static SerialPort _serialPort1 = new SerialPort();  
        private string _portName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["COM"];    
        private string FilesPath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Path"];   
        private System.Timers.Timer PrintTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        private System.Timers.Timer ErrorTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(3500); 
        private bool PrintTimerIsActive = true; 
        private string HsCOMerrorStrings, PrintErrors;  

        #endregion

        public Form1() 
        {
            _serialPort1.PortName = _portName; 
            _serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 1000;
            _IfFileExistsPrint();
        }

        private void _IfFileExistsPrint()
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(FilesPath))
                _filesToPrint.Add(file); 

            FileSystemWatcher SysWatch = new FileSystemWatcher(FilesPath, "*.*");
            SysWatch.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(SysWatch_Created);
            SysWatch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            PrintTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
            PrintTimer.Start();

            ErrorTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(ErrorTimer_Elapsed);
        }

        private void SysWatch_Created(object Sender, FileSystemEventArgs w)
        {
            _filesToPrint.Add(w.FullPath);
        }


        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_filesToPrint.Count > 0 && PrintTimerIsActive)
            {
                PrintTimer.Stop();  
                SendFilesToCom(_filesToPrint[0].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Printing file :" + _filesToPrint[0].ToString());
                File.Delete(_filesToPrint[0].ToString());   
                _filesToPrint.RemoveAt(0);  
                _filesToPrint.TrimToSize(); 
                Console.Write(HsCOMerrorStrings);
                PrintTimer.Start(); 

                PrintErrors = ErrorCheck(HsCOMerrorStrings);
            }
        }

        private void ErrorTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs d)
        {
            if (!_serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    _serialPort1.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Data);
                }
            }

            try
            {
                HsCOMerrorStrings = _serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                _serialPort1.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Data);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(ErrorCheck(HsCOMerrorStrings));
        }

        private string ErrorCheck(string COMHostStatusReturn)
        {
            string ErrorsReturn = System.String.Empty;
            string[] COMCode = COMHostStatusReturn.Split(',');

            if (COMCode[1] == "1") { ErrorsReturn += "Carta Esaurita" + Environment.NewLine; }
            if (COMCode[2] == "1") { ErrorsReturn += "Stampante in Pausa" + Environment.NewLine; }
            if (COMCode[5] == "1") { ErrorsReturn += "Memoria Stampante Esaurita" + Environment.NewLine; }
            if (COMCode[9] == "1") { ErrorsReturn += "Memoria RAM corrotta" + Environment.NewLine; }
            if (COMCode[10] == "1") { ErrorsReturn += "Temperatura troppo bassa" + Environment.NewLine; }
            if (COMCode[11] == "1") { ErrorsReturn += "Temperatura troppo alta" + Environment.NewLine; }

            if (COMCode[7] == "1") { ErrorsReturn += "Partial Format Flag" + Environment.NewLine; }

            if (ErrorsReturn != System.String.Empty)    
            {

                if (PrintTimerIsActive == true)         
                {
                    PrintTimer.Stop();                  

                    if (!ErrorTimer.Enabled)             
                        ErrorTimer.Start();             

                    MessageBox.Show(ErrorsReturn);      
                }
                PrintTimerIsActive = false;             
            }
            else                                        
            {                                   
                if (PrintTimerIsActive == false)        
                {
                    ErrorTimer.Stop();                  
                    PrintTimer.Start();                 
                    PrintTimerIsActive = true;          
                }
            }

            return ErrorsReturn;
        }

        private void SendFilesToCom(string filePath)
        {
            if (!_serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    _serialPort1.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            try
            {
                using (System.IO.TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        _serialPort1.WriteLine(line);
                    }

                    HsCOMerrorStrings = _serialPort1.ReadLine();
                    reader.Close(); 
                    _serialPort1.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're swallowing exceptions in the important portions of your code, it is hard to say. It would be easier - also for you - if you handled all exceptions properly, for example to see whether the port is even closed correctly.

Comment: You'll need to get rid of ErrorTimer entirely, that cannot work.  Do **not** constantly close and open the port.  There's an internal worker thread that needs time to exit after a Close() call before the port can be opened again.

Comment: Thorsten, Well, where should I put them? How?

@Hans, What about putting a sleep or a longer timer error Interval?

Comment: @HansPassant Read the post above, also, what you suggest to control error removing periodically?

Comment: I put a 10 second timer with no result

Comment: I modified the ErrorTimer_Elapsed as following:

 _serialPort1.Close();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            string xxx = _serialPort1.IsOpen ? "Aperta" : "Chiusa";
            Console.WriteLine("La porta è " + xxx);
            if (!_serialPort1.IsOpen)
            

Port now starts as closed but I still get "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll"